# nullpointerexception at bluetooth connect

Tags: android, bluetooth, nullpointerexception, bluetooth-lowenergy

android beginner here.

i'm trying to run the bluetooth low energy sample from google  http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html on my nexus 5.

i can sucessfully start the app, scan and display available devices, but when i try to connect to one of them, i end up having a java.lang.NullPointerException :

```
    08-06 12:50:05.333: D/BluetoothAdapter(11840): stopLeScan()
08-06 12:50:05.353: W/ActivityManager(765): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.bledevicetest/.BluetoothLeService } U=0: not found
08-06 12:50:05.403: I/ActivityManager(765): Displayed com.bledevicetest/.DeviceControlActivity: +73ms
08-06 12:50:09.783: D/BluetoothAdapter(11840): stopLeScan()
08-06 12:50:14.483: D/AndroidRuntime(11840): Shutting down VM
08-06 12:50:14.483: W/dalvikvm(11840): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ed4ba8)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840): Process: com.bledevicetest, PID: 11840
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at com.bledevicetest.DeviceControlActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(DeviceControlActivity.java:217)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:546)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-06 12:50:14.483: E/AndroidRuntime(11840):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 12:50:14.493: W/ActivityManager(765):   Force finishing activity com.bledevicetest/.DeviceControlActivity
```

any ideas where this might come from ?

at the line 217 :  mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);

also, i noticed this error before trying the connection :

08-06 12:50:05.353: W/ActivityManager(765): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.bledevicetest/.BluetoothLeService } U=0: not found

would this be related to the issue ?

**EDIT  :  SOLUTION FOUND**

i did not declare the service in the manifest. that was the problem.
problem solved !

Comment: Can you declare Bluetooth service in manifest?

Comment: same when you create an activity :

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it. This won't add anything to your reputation, but it will keep things tidy when others are looking at the index of questions and when search engines index the site.

Comment: yes, i will post the solution.
but since  i do not have enouh posts on stackoverflow, i have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that in the manifest file i had :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.bledevicetest.BluetoothLeService"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bluetooth_le_service" >
    </activity>
```

so, i changed it to this :

```
<service 
        android:name="com.bledevicetest.BluetoothLeService" 
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
```

and it worked.